# What's the namespace of AJAX DNA?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

http://www.dotnetage.com/sites/home/djme-2-demo.html

The dna keep appearing with red squiggly line, what's the namespace of the following MVC library?

```
@{
    Ajax.Dna().TreeView("Tree1")
                   .ShowCheckboxs(true)
                   .Items(items =>
                   {
                       items.Add("Accordion", "#", Url.Content("~/webshared/home/images/dj_icons/icon_accordion.gif"))
                               .Items(subItems =>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [home page](http://www.dotnetage.com/sites/home/djme.html) seems pretty self explanatory and more specifically the *Installation* section.

#### For Razor

1.Add DJME2 namespaces in *~/Views/web.config* like below:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
           ...   
     <pages>   
      <namespaces>
           ...
        <add namespace="DNA.Mvc" />        
        <add namespace="DNA.Mvc.jQuery" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

2.Add css links and script links in *~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml* header tag

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/default/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/default/dna.ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.farbtastic.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/djme-2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3.Add script render method on the bottom of the *~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml*

```
...
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Html.RenderScripts()
</body>
...
```

#### For ASP.NET MVC 2

1.Add DJME 2 namespaces in *~/web.config* like below:

```
<system.web> 
          ... 
       <pages> 
          <namespaces> 
                 ...                
                <add namespace="DNA.Mvc" /> 
                <add namespace="DNA.Mvc.jQuery" /> 
          </namespaces>
      </pages> 
</system.web>
```

2.Add css links and script links in *~/Views/Shared/Site.Master* head tag

```
<link href="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/themes/default/jquery-ui.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/themes/default/dna.ui.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.farbtastic.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/djme-2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3.Add script render method on the bottom of the *~/Views/Shared/Site.Master*

```
   ...
<body>
   ....
<%=Html.RenderScripts() %>
</body>
</html>
```